# Why does rails resource not generate edit and new paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a `PasswordsController` to handle password recovery and I want to route it as a singular resource.

The code from the router:

```
resource :password
```

I want to use the generated routes as follows:

```
/password/new    # User enters email
/password/create # Send email with link to password edit form with token
/password/edit   # User edits password
/password/update # Password is changed
```

But for some reason rails only generates the following routes:

```
password GET    /password(.:format) passwords#show
         PATCH  /password(.:format) passwords#update
         PUT    /password(.:format) passwords#update
         DELETE /password(.:format) passwords#destroy
         POST   /password(.:format) passwords#create
```

According to the documentation there should also be an `edit` path and a `new` path.

Why are they missing?

(This is rails 5.2.1.1)

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, problem must lie somewhere in my app's configuration as this is not reproducible with a clean rails app.

Comment: @AjayBarot: the answer you linked says `resource` should generate new/edit routes. What were you trying to say?

Comment: Can't reproduce in a brand new rails 5.2.1.1 app. I see all 6 routes. Something else in your code is interfering.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, it's probably some setting in my app. I just don't know what it could be. I already tested it with a development.rb from a fresh rails app. No success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have an api_only app.
In that case Rails omit edit and new path.
see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1230

Comment: Ah, good find. new/edit routes don't make sense in api, indeed.

Comment: That was it! I totally missed that. But it also seems like this behavior is not documented.

Comment: @lukad: does it need to be documented, though? In your api-only app without a GUI, what would you use `edit` for? Its whole purpose is to render the blank form. So rails does the right thing silently, as in many other cases.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The app used to be a strict API only app until I tried adding this feature. So this is definitely an edge case, but documenting it wouldn't hurt. I'll check if I can create a PR for that.